# How can I separate tabs headings from their bodies with angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-tabset

In an angularjs project, I am using the uib-tabset directive in order to display tabs. I would like to display a left panel that is common to all tabs. So I have to add a div before or after the uib-tabset directive.

By default, the headings part is directly on top of tabs body.
[image]

In the generated structure, I would like to include the panel inside the tabs (visually) :
[image: same side panel for all tabs]

With uib-tabsets, the generated structure is like this:

```
<panel>
<tabs-headings>
<tabs-bodies>
```

With this structure, the only way I have found is to edit the css and play with position properties (left/top) in order to move the headings on top of the side panel, but I find this risky.
Another way would be to duplicate the panel code inside of each tab, but I find this bad too.

Instead I would like to generate this so it would be easier to create the css :

```
<tabs-heading>
<panel>
<tabs-bodies>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve that behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Lol. Just saw that I'm 10 months late.

I just ran into what you're talking about. If you are dynamically rendering content in each tab using `ng-repeat`, this would avoid having to remake the side panel a bunch of times.

```
  <div class="tabWrapper">
    <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">

      <div class="sidePanel">{{tab.sidepanel}}</div> 
      <div class="tabContent">{{tab.content}}</div>

    </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
```

You wouldn't need to mess with absolute positioning either:

```
.sidePanel {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
```

*OR*, if you're using `angular-ui-router`, you could accomplish the static side panel by using abstract states.

**config.js**

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('root.tabs', {
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'TabsCtrl as vm',
      templateUrl: 'templates/app-layout/tabs.tpl.html'
    })   
    .state('root.tabs.view', {
      url: '/tabsview',
      templateUrl: 'templates/app-layout/sidepanel.tpl.html'
    });
```

**tabs.tpl.html**

```
   <div>
      <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">

        <div class="sidePanelContainer" ui-view></div>

        <div class="tabContent">{{tab.content}}</div>
        </uib-tab>
      </uib-tabset>
    </div>
```

**sidepanel.tpl.html**

```
<div class="sidePanel">
  <input type="text" value="1234">
  <input type="text" value="4321">
</div>
```

See also: 
[what is the purpose of use abstract state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423272/what-is-the-purpose-of-use-abstract-state)

Hope this helps