# What does 'abstract:true' mean in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

abstract: true is often used along with url:' '
What action do they perform and why are they used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181532/why-give-an-abstract-true-state-a-url

Comment: You could read up on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423272/what-is-the-purpose-of-use-abstract-state)

Comment: See this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181532/why-give-an-abstract-true-state-a-url